# How to delete duplicate from 140 GB SQL server table where 30% records are duplicate without causing overheads like transaction logs full?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to delete duplicate from 140 GB SQL server table where 30% records are duplicate without causing overheads like transaction logs full?

table doesn't have primary key.

Comment: all three columns in table make it unique row. no clustered index but non cluster index.

Comment: What would be the best way to identify duplicates in the table when data size is huge?

Comment: If you have the time, then doing them in very small batches while monitoring the size of the transaction log and basically pausing as it starts to fill would work. If time is a factor, you may need to switch to SIMPLE recovery model. 

You should post, obfuscated if you want, a table definition and the nonclustered index definition, so people can give more targeted advice.

Comment: Start by adding a clustered index on your table. Having a heap with non-custered index is not a good design for 99% of the cases (and I bet you are not in this 1%). Don't create the index as "unique" for the implementation. Once all your data is ordered it will be easier for SQL to run the query to delete the duplicate in small batch.

Comment: I have xml file for an account, I pulled key/value pairs of that file into table with account number indicating the file name. this has been repeated for 1000 accounts and the table is backup table now for all accounts. since I load files incrementally through SSIS looping account number I created account number as non clustered index. Now I could see some of the files/Account number are loaded multiple times that I want to delete. How could I find duplicates on this huge table is something I am looking for, also once identified how to run delete probably in batches?

Comment: Things are going to be made a little more difficult as deletes on a heap do *not* behave like you would expect with traditional table (which don't always work how you'd expect depending on how you insert/update data). https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/01/heaps-deletes-optimistic-isolation-levels/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no Primary Key then you have no Foreign Keys referencing it.
That leaves you in the privileged position of being able to *remove* the table and completely recreate it or, rather, create a *new* table with only the rows you want, then drop the original table and rename the new table, something like this.

```
create table t2 
( a ... 
, b ... 
, c ... 
) 
primary key ( a, b, c ); 

insert into t2 ( a, b, c ) 
select a, b, c 
from t1 
where ... 
; 

drop table t1 ; 

EXEC sp_rename 't2', 't1' ;
```

Of course, how you identify the rows that you want to take across is up to you.

Comment: I have xml file for an account, I pulled key/value pairs of that file into table with account number indicating the file name. this has been repeated for 1000 accounts and the table is backup table now for all accounts. since I load files incrementally through SSIS looping account number I created account number as non clustered index. Now I could see some of the files/Account number are loaded multiple times that I want to delete. How could I find duplicates on this huge table is something I am looking for, also once identified how to run delete probably in batches?

Comment: insert into t2 ( a, b, c ) 
select distinct  a, b, c 
from t1  --would this work on this huge table?

Comment: The first sentence is not true. Foreign keys can reference any unique constraint, not just the primary key.

Comment: ... and an FK can even reference a column with a unique index (without a constraint definition at all).

Comment: Since I had the non clustered index on Account number, Created following procedure to loop through and delete duplicate data in batches using SSIS FELC container.                     create proc deleteDups  @Accountnumber nvarchar(30)
as
begin
    WITH table_nameCTE AS  
(  
   SELECT*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  Accountnumber, [key], [value]
           ORDER BY  Accountnumber, [key], [value]) alias_name  
   FROM XML_Doc_bkp  where accountnumber=@Accountnumber
)  delete table_nameCTE WHERE alias_name >1 end